# Getting Persistence Already in Use error from MQTT

Tags: java, mqtt

I am getting the following exception from the mqtt broker when I am trying to create a new MqttClient. The error is here ---

```
Caused by: Persistence already in use (32200)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.open(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:108) [mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar:]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:273) [mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar:]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:222) [mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar:]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:134) [mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar:]
at com.ericsson.asdp.virtualassist.notification.messaging.MQTTHandler.createClient(MQTTHandler.java:61) [classes:]
at com.ericsson.asdp.virtualassist.notification.messaging.MQTTMessagingService.receieve(MQTTMessagingService.java:52) [classes:]
... 44 more
```

Here is the code for my java class `receive()` method from where I am trying to connect to mqtt ---

```
MqttClient subClient = null;
try {
    subClient = mqttHandler.createClient(userId, brokerURL);
    MQTTNotificationSubscriber notificationSub = new MQTTNotificationSubscriber(mqttHandler);
    notificationSub.setUserId(userId);

    subClient.setCallback(notificationSub);
    mqttHandler.subscribe(subClient, userId);
    // do something here
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error in receive " + e.getMessage());
        throw new VirtualAssistServicesException(e.getMessage(), e);
}  finally {
    try {
        mqttHandler.disconnect(subClient);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        throw new VirtualAssistServicesException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

And here is the MQTTHandler class `createClient()` method ---

```
MqttClient subClient = null;

try {
    subClient = new MqttClient(brokerURL, clientId);

} catch (MqttException e) {

}
```

When I create the client for a userId first time it works. From second time onwards it fails with the above exception. I am using `clean-session=false` here.

If anyone has any idea please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like both clients are trying to use the same file for persistence.
Javadocs for [MqttDefaultFilePersistence.open()](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/persist/MqttDefaultFilePersistence.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says

> Initialise the persistent store. If a persistent store exists for this client ID then open it, otherwise create a new one. If the persistent store is already open then just return. An application may use the same client ID to connect to many different servers, so the client ID in conjunction with the connection will uniquely identify the persistence store required.
>   **Throws:** MqttPersistenceException - if there was a problem opening the
>   persistent store.

I suppose the file is already open, you must use a different `clientId` in your code for each one of your Mqtt clients.

Comment: The problem does get resolved if I use MemoryPersistence instead of the default FilePersistence. @Alessandro, thx for ur post. For my case I do not wish to maintain separate clientID-s; that's a requirement of sort. Hence I am now using MemoryPersistence which works fine; at least for now :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because in both client you are using same persistence name.

```
client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.1.100:1883", "One");
```

In the next thread you are using the same:

```
client1 = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.1.100:1883", "One");
```

The persistence name should be different for each connection you want to make. You have to make change like this in client1:

```
client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.1.100:1883", "Two");
```

Comment: the only thing you are changing is the client id, which is then used to generate a persistence directory if one is not specified